# How does tx fee calculation work when txin and txout are similar amounts?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

[This website](http://bitcoinfees.com) has an example called "When Too Much is Not Enough" on its main page. I'll quote it an case this is changed in the future:

> Suppose you have only two outputs in your wallet, worth 1 XBT and 2
>   XBT. You want to buy something for 2.999 XBT. The coin selection code
>   has no choice; it has to select both coins to get a big enough total
>   to make the transaction. That means the change will be 0.001 XBT,
>   which triggers the 0.0001 XBT fee for having an output that's less
>   than 0.01 XBT. As a result your transaction will fail, because the
>   amount you're sending plus the fee is more than you have.
>
> What this means is that there's no way of spending 2.999 XBT when you
>   have 3 XBT. You could send the full 3 XBT to the vendor without a fee
>   (assuming the outputs are sufficiently old to satisfy step 3), but
>   some vendors ask you to send the exact amount they specify.

Since the 1 BTC input and the 2 BTC input are interchangeable in this respect, let's (for the sake of simplicity) settle that the bitcoin client decides to send the 2 BTC input in full for this example.

Then it has to split the 1 BTC input into a 0.999 BTC output and a 0.001 BTC output. I assume that doing so requires a fee because one of the outputs is smaller than 0.01 BTC. So 0.0001 BTC have to be paid for this. This means that there now is a 0.999 BTC junk and a 0.0009 BTC. The 2 BTC junk and the 0.999 BTC junk are send away and the 0.0009 BTC junk remains at its owner.

Can you tell me what I did wrong to get an outcome different from the one of the authors of that website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the example is erroneous. They also neglect to consider that you could send 2.999 XBT and designate all of the remainder of 0.001 XBT as fee.